# Create shortcut into home screen in Android 9.0

Tags: android, shortcut, homescreen, android-9.0-pie

I've used the following code for creating shortcut

```
private void createShortCut() {
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);

        shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false); 
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
    }
```

The above code is working well in android 7.0
But it doesn't work in android 8.0 and above.
How can I add shortcut into home screen in android 8.0 and above?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this article:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts

You should use `ShortcutManager` for that purpose.

Comment: I've already see that document. But that code doesn't create the shortcut in home screen. Thank you for your time.